# JS sum JSON value based on date month

Tags: javascript, json

## JSON Data:

```
{
"client 1": [
    {
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "2020-11-15",
        "total_after_tax": 174060
    },
    {
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "2020-11-07",
        "total_after_tax": 94904
    }
],
"client 2": [
    {
        "customer_branch_id": 127,
        "date": "2020-11-16",
        "total_after_tax": 128160
    },
    {
        "customer_branch_id": 127,
        "date": "2020-11-07",
        "total_after_tax": 82320
    }
]
```

}

I am trying to sum `total_after_tax` data based on ***month*** from `data` field.

Also I want to set `total_after_tax` value to `0` if month doesn't exist.

## For example for `client 1`:

```
{
"client 1": [
    {
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "1",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "2",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "3",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "4",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "5",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "6",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "7",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "8",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "9",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "10",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "11",
        "total_after_tax": 268964
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "12",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    }
]
```

}

All months `total_after_tax=0` except `date=11` because its the only month that have result.

Comment: and what've you tried?

Comment: "_I am trying to sum..._" - let us help you determine why what you've tried doesn't work. But you have to show us some code you've tried. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve.

Comment: There are several open questions, beyond the requests to see your own effort.  Are you looking to extract for a given client identifier, or do you want to structure an object with an entry for each client?  Can one client identifier have multiple branch ids?  If so, do they get totaled separately?  Why is the output field named `date` rather then the more logical `month`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach assumes that you want to extract the monthly data for a given client and a specific year.  It could easily be extended to create an object keyed by client (and year?) with the same structure.

It makes the assumption that a client has a single branch id associated.  If not, we would need to understand the required output format for multiples.

```js
const sum = (ns) =>
  ns.reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  
const clientMonthlyTotal = (input, client, year) => {
  const custData = (input [client] || [])
    .filter (({date}) => date.slice(0, 4) == year)
  return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] .map (month => ({
    customer_branch_id: (custData [0] || {}) .customer_branch_id,
    date: month,
    total_after_taxes: sum (
      custData .filter (
        ({date}) => date .startsWith (`${year}-${String (month) .padStart (2, '0')}`)
      ) .map (x => x .total_after_tax)
    )
  }))
}
                                                                 
const input = {"client 1": [{customer_branch_id: 128, date: "2020-11-15", total_after_tax: 174060}, {customer_branch_id: 128, date: "2020-11-07", total_after_tax: 94904}], "client 2": [{customer_branch_id: 127, date: "2020-11-16", total_after_tax: 128160}, {customer_branch_id: 127, date: "2020-11-07", total_after_tax: 82320}]}

console .log (
  clientMonthlyTotal (input, 'client 1', '2020')
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We include the helper function `sum`, which simply totals an array of numbers.

The main function first extracts the results for the client and filters to the relevant year.  Then we map over the months, returning an object for each, with a `branch_id` taken from the first result (see the assumption above), a `date` referring to the month, and a `total` field found by filtering the customer data to those records matching the month, then extracting their `total` properties, and totaling the results with `sum`.

There is an inefficiency here if this is to be used on really large data set (client object with hundreds of thousands of records).  We run the `filter` function against the whole set for each month.  An alternative would be to group the records by their month fields.  While that would not be terribly difficult, it would add complexity to the code.

If your data is constrained to a single year, we could simplify this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

---

You could try this for a start . However, you have to do more modifications to this code.

```
const data = {
"client_1": [
    {
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "1",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "2",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "3",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "4",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "5",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "6",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "7",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "8",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "9",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "10",
        "total_after_tax": 0
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "11",
        "total_after_tax": 268964
    },{
        "customer_branch_id": 128,
        "date": "12",
        "total_after_tax": 2
    }
]};
const date = '12';
const total = data['client_1'].filter(record => record['date'] === date)
.map((record) => parseFloat(record['total_after_tax']))
.reduce((accumulator, current) => accumulator + current)

console.log(total)
```

Comment: If I read the question correctly, this is backward.  The monthly data report is supposed to be the output, based on the day-to-day report ("JSON Data").  Of course I may be wrong, but that's how the question seems to read.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good approach would be to iterate through all the client keys of your JSON using a for...in loop.

Inside this for, you can create an Array of 12 elements using the spread operator and map them to introduce the desired content.

I've supposed the customer branch id is unique for each client, so that's why i relied on the first element to set it.

Finally, with the reduce method you can compare each month with the current index given by the .map. If it's the same, then you can add the value of total_after_tax to the accumulator.

In order to parse the date from the current value (curr.date) you can use the Date class as new Date(curr.date)

Note that the getMonth method gives the month from 0 to 11, that's why I added 1 in the if statement as well as in the initial value of the accumulator (month: index + 1)

***EDIT:** I've assumed all the data is contained within a calendar year.*

```js
const data = {
    "client 1": [
        {
            "customer_branch_id": 128,
            "date": "2020-11-15",
            "total_after_tax": 174060
        },
        {
            "customer_branch_id": 128,
            "date": "2020-11-07",
            "total_after_tax": 94904
        }
    ],
    "client 2": [
        {
            "customer_branch_id": 127,
            "date": "2020-11-16",
            "total_after_tax": 128160
        },
        {
            "customer_branch_id": 127,
            "date": "2020-11-07",
            "total_after_tax": 82320
        }] 
}
const result = {};

for (let client in data) {
    result[client] = [...Array(12)].map((element, index) => {
        return ({
            customer_branch_id: data[client][0].customer_branch_id,
            ...data[client].reduce((acc, curr) => {
                const date = new Date(curr.date);
                if (acc.date === date.getMonth() + 1) {
                    acc.total_after_tax += curr.total_after_tax;
                } 
                return acc
            }, {
                date: index + 1,
                total_after_tax: 0
            })
        })
    })
}
        
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This seems to assume that all the data is contained within a calendar year.  I simply can't tell if that's true from the question.  I will add an answer with some different assumptions.